# Mocking private scope identifier with eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope, eval

While programming a server application for multiplayer games, I got an idea for cleaning up my code a bit.

I'm heavily using the `Module Pattern` for my application and use a convention for calling exposed functions `public[Function name]` and privates `private[Function name]`. The `public` prefix helps in the return assignment:

```
return {
    get : publicGet
}
```

But the private identifier names are just for show and make calling them a bit cumbersome. However, completely removing the `private` prefix makes the code a bit less readable. So I thought of using the reserved `private` keyword as you would in, for example, Java.

For doing this I thought I could use `eval` like this:

```
var private = eval('') // Just an empty assignment so it does nothing.
```

So I can write my private function like this:

```
private function initiateGameMatchmaker(game) {
    // Code...
}
```

Instead of:

```
function privateInitiateGameMatchmaker(game) {
    // Code...
}
```

Would this be acceptable or do you regard this as a filthy hack and thus as a definite no-no?

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't actually work. Just use a convention and stick with it. Maybe `_initiateGameMatchmaker`.

Comment: Acceptable or not, it won't work. `private` will be `undefined`, and `privare function foo(){}` will throw a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`

Comment: My bad, I thought I got it to work but I was running an out-of-date version. I'll remove the question in a moment.

Comment: Don't remove the question. It may not be possible to do it this way, but it's still a valid question. A _"No, it's not possible"_ is a better answer than no answer at all, if someone looks for a question like this.

Comment: I'll leave it then, thanks.

Comment: `private` is a [**reserved keyword**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in _JavaScript_

Comment: @PaulS.: "_So I thought of using the **reserved `private` keyword** as you would in, for example, Java._" He knows ;-)

Comment: @PaulS. I know, I even mentioned it in the question. I thought I could outsmart it due to the dynamism in Javascript, but quickly found the error of my way. I was a bit premature with my question. Nevertheless, I'll leave the question and the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceptable or not, it won't work.

`private` will be `undefined`, and `private function foo(){}` will throw a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`.

Don't try to mold JavaScript into the conventions of a language it's not.

Comment: It's normal in the company to try and mold it to OO-practices and even though I strongly disagree, I thought this would be a nice way to code to the company expectations. As mentioned in an other comment: I didn't notice I was running an out-of-date version and so I thought it worked. What is the generally acceptable convention for this?

Comment: [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) are often referred to, when conventions are concerned. But it's a matter of preference which you'd follow. For private variables / functions, I believe a underscore prefix (`_myPrivateVar / function _myPrivateFunction(){}`) is most common.